# Check list of users of exited in the Firestore users collection from Cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on Cloud function to get the registered contacts to the app as the following:

cloud function input: user list of contacts
cloud function response: list of contacts that already registered on the app
process: get the users contacts and search for each contact if existed in the users collection

how can I implement it?
for now, I am trying for loop for each contact to check if exist in the DB.

advise.

Comment: You could search for them in batches, using [getAll](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.12.x/Firestore#getAll)

Comment: @JasonBerryman, thanks for your answer, but what I need as the following, I have the list of contacts (for example 800 contact) I got them as a parameter and I already have the list of users (for example 5000 contacts), how to get the existed users contacts for the 5000 DB contact ? is there firestore query to get the registered contacts at the DB ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  This sounds like the kind of query that you'd need a relational database for.  Is this a one-off process or do you need to keep repeating it?  You could export both lists to BigQuery and check it there